# Why would Snape still be well informed about Order plans?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

When we see Snape's memories in DH Dumbledore's portrait tells Snape that he must tell Voldemort the right date Harry will be moved from Privet Dr because Voldemort believes Snape so well informed. But why would he still be considered well informed about the Order and Ministry's plans now that both believe him to be a Death Eater who murdered Dumbledore?

Comment: I don't have a quote at hand right now, but wasn't it said that Snape confunded a ministry worker to find out how Harry was to be moved?

Comment: I asked the slightly related question as to HOW he was told here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63974/how-did-dumbledore-manage-to-tell-snape-to-give-voldemort-harrys-correct-moving. The answer is in your question: Dumbledore('s portrait) tells him, but the problem you pointed out remains.

Comment: @GeorgeT How would doing that work? But no - Severus actually Confunded Mundungus to suggest it to the Order but forget who told him to do so. This is in his memories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't understand the point of your question.

The Order and the Ministry did NOT tell Snape when Harry was moved.

**Dumbledore** (via his <strike>Force Ghost</strike> portrait) did - which you even mention in the question.

And unlike the Order and the Ministry, HE knew that Snape was the Good Guy since he arranged things that way.

Answer (score 4):

In the specific case you mention, it isn't so much that Snape was well informed, as that he planted the idea himself:
Snape confunded Mundungus to plant the idea to use polyjuice potion. During that time, he could have either extracted the date from Mundunges, or planted a suggestion for the date.

Comment: The reason Snape has to plant the 7 Potters idea is because Dumbledore tells him he must give Voldemort the correct date because Voldemort considers Snape so well informed on Order stuff. But at that time Snape had been proven to be a Death Eater who murdered Dumbledore so why would Voldemort think he would still be getting insider spy info? Especially when he has a number of other spies high in the Ministry who haven't been outed.

Comment: @jossgod You just said it yourself: "Voldemort considers Snape so well informed on Order stuff". Snape needs to stay on top of Voldemort's best servants list, partially because it is safer for him if he is deemed the most loyal, trustworthy and useful one, partially because beeing on top of that list makes him the prime candidate to take the position of headmaster at Hogwarts (where he can protect the students from the Carrows). Proving that he is better informed than all other spies Voldemort has, is one of the best ways to stay on top of that list.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't say about the Ministry guys, but in the Order, it has been mentioned many times, that if Dumbledore trusts Snape completely, there is no reason for others not to. Professor Lupin says this to Harry at some point. Some of them are cautious and suspicious, like Sirius Black, but he is always there at their meetings and everything. That's what I think.

Comment: Snape is always at the meetings **before** the events of *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: The question was about **after** the events of HbP, when they all know he killed Dumbledore.

Comment: @ Mooz and @DVK: Yes, your point is correct. I don't remember much from the books anymore, but after Dumbledore died, the book did not revolve much around Snape's involvement in information gathering. Still I would think that since he has been a double-spy for so long, he must have other ways to get information. I think, even the order did not have proper headquarters after Half Blood Prince. Maybe he got it from some Ministry Members, who were secretly in with Voldemort.

Comment: Veda who got what from Ministry Members who were secretly in with Voldemort?

Comment: After he kills Dumbledore, Moody even puts up a block against Snape entering the Order's headquarters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is about trust. Dumbledore trusted that Snape is on his side, therefore he gave him that information (or his portrait did).

Voldemort believed Snape is on his side, he believed he owned Snape and he knew that Dumbledore trusted Snape, but he thought that Dumbledore´s trust was misplaced, since Voldemort was sure that Snape was loyal to him - and Voldemort believed that precisely because Snape managed to look like he was fooling Dumbledore all the way. Therefore he believed the information he received.

So both sides, Voldemort and Dumbledore, believed that Snape is manipulating the other side and is loyal only to them. They both believed him. Only the Order didn´t believe Snape.

Comment: But why would Voldemort think Snape had information on the Order when he'd already left it?

Comment: @TheDarkLord There are two explanations that comes to mind:
1. I´m not sure how portraits works, but i believe that the portrait was a projection of "old" Dumbledore, when the picture was taken. Therefore, Voldemort may think that Snape could actually fool the portrait. Heck, he might even thought that Dumbledore was foolish enough to let himself killed for the greater good, and therefore he would still put false trust in Snape.
2. Voldemort can simply assume, that Snape has a lot of other informators or other magical methods to spy on the Order - that he kept some spying device behind.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Snape was simply the most resourceful servant, so Voldemort trusted he will continue to deliver good information despite the fact that he was no longer in the Order. If Snape stopped continuing the good work, he would get rid of him. Therefore it was essential for Snape to prove himself that even though he left, he can still be useful - thus the whole situation happened like that. Voldemort could be suspicious, but he didn´t have any reason yet to stop trusting Snape.